# About layouts using awt and swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, gridbaglayout

So I was trying to go for a basic calculator layout made with `GridBagLayout` and after going through a few documents I came up with this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Calculator");
        f.setSize(1000, 550);
        f.setResizable(false);

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        JTextField out = new JTextField();
        out.setColumns(15);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        //c.gridwidth=4;
        p1.add(out, c);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("CLEAR");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b1, c);

        JButton b2 = new JButton("ERASE");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b2, c);

        JButton b3 = new JButton("ROOT");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b3, c);

        JButton b4 = new JButton("÷");
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b4, c);

        JButton b5 = new JButton("7");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b5, c);

        JButton b6 = new JButton("8");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b6, c);

        JButton b7 = new JButton("9");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b7, c);

        JButton b8 = new JButton("X");
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b8, c);

        JButton b9 = new JButton("4");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b9, c);

        JButton b10 = new JButton("5");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b10, c);

        JButton b11 = new JButton("6");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b11, c);

        JButton b12 = new JButton("+");
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b12, c);

        JButton b13 = new JButton("1");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b13, c);

        JButton b14 = new JButton("2");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b14, c);

        JButton b15 = new JButton("3");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b15, c);

        JButton b16 = new JButton("-");
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b16, c);

        JButton b17 = new JButton();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        p1.add(b17, c);

        JButton b18 = new JButton("0");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b18, c);

        JButton b19 = new JButton();
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b19, c);

        JButton b20 = new JButton("=");
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 5;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        p1.add(b20, c);


        f.add(p1);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This resulted in something like this:

[image]

So I uncommented this line to extend the `JTextField` out until the end:

```
//c.gridwidth=4;
```

It did something bizarre like this:

[image]

I could not figure out why only one column of the grid was being shown.
What might be causing this? What do I do to fix this? I want the `JTextField` to extend across all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding weights to every button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `gridwidth` value for the next component since you are reusing the same constraints object:

```
c.gridwidth=4;
p1.add(out,c);

JButton b1= new JButton("CLEAR");
c.gridx=0;
c.gridy=1;
c.gridwidth=1; // added
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
p1.add(b1,c);
```

Now a gridwidth of 1 will be used for the remaining components.